# Solution to $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(1+u\right)^{2}}\frac{\log u}{1+au^{b}}~\mathrm{d}u$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does any of you know the solution to

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(1+u\right)^{2}}\frac{\log u}{1+au^{b}}~\mathrm{d}u$$

with $a>0$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Have you tried turning $1+au^b$ into its geometric series form, since it’s valid on the interval from 0 to 1? Not sure if it would work but seems like a nice first step to me.

Comment: Yep here’s a hint. This worked for me: turn this into the geometric series, then generalize whatever ends up inside of the sum operator (after switching Integral and sum) using Feynman integration with the variable you’re introducing somewhere easily placed in the denominator of the expression. You should be able to find a nice initial condition for the function of the introduced variable evaluated at 0. You may see something to do with the Lerch transcendent.